# Quartz trigger start time before current time

Tags: java, scheduling, quartz-scheduler

Lets say that I have a quartz trigger `SimpleTrigger` that fires every second and start time is set to 12:00:00 today. It seems that when I schedule that trigger at 12:00:10 then it fires immediately **10** times. Is there a way to avoid  that kind of behaviour or should I just manually set start time to 12:00:10 before scheduling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the misfire instruction policy for your particular trigger type.
This doc explains what are the available options for the SimpleTrigger
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05

By default SimpleTrigger has MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_SMART_POLICY policy active.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at [setMisfireInstruction()](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/org/quartz/Trigger.html#setMisfireInstruction%28int%29) and choose the most suitable instruction supported by [SimpleTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/org/quartz/SimpleTrigger.html#MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW).